# Getting the number of shapes with in a layer on visio using VBA

Tags: vba, shapes, layer, visio

I am trying to create a macro in VBA with Visio, that would count the amount of shapes in a layer and report the number. Would anyone have any ideas or pointers on how to approach this?

I know how to report the number of shapes in a entire workbook but I'm needing to report the quantity in a layer to see if it even has items assigned to it. I thought something like `Layers.count` would work but I'm not sure if that's even the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`CreateSelection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.page.createselection) method on Page and then return the count from that.

For example:

```vb
Public Sub GetTheCount()
    Dim layerName As String
    Dim count As Integer
    
    layerName = "Flowchart"
    
    count = CountShapesOnLayer(ActivePage, layerName)
    Debug.Print "There are " & count & " shapes on layer " & layerName
End Sub


Public Function CountShapesOnLayer(ByRef vPag As Visio.Page, layerName As String) As Integer
    If Not vPag Is Nothing Then
        Dim vLayer As Visio.Layer
        Dim vSel As Visio.Selection
 
        Set vLayer = vPag.Layers.ItemU(layerName)
        Set vSel = vPag.CreateSelection(Visio.VisSelectionTypes.visSelTypeByLayer, _
                                    Visio.VisSelectMode.visSelModeSkipSuper, _
                                    vLayer)
        CountShapesOnLayer = vSel.count
    Else
        CountShapesOnLayer = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Note the SelectMode argument, which in the above will give you the top level shapes, but bear in mind that you may need to change this if you're dealing with sub-shapes (in a group).

Comment: Careful John, there is a nasty potential problem there, "Set vLayer = vPag.Layers.ItemU(layerName)" could be correct, but more often "Set vLayer = vPag.Layers.Item(layerName)" would be the normal usage.

Comment: and this won't count shapes that have been set as non-selectable. So many 'gotchas' in Visio!

Comment: Thank you both @JohnGoldensmith and @PaulHerber! A great example and food for thought! I was stumped on this for a bit.

Comment: Hi @Paul, I think in code I would use universal names otherwise you've got to contend with localized names and any changes the user might have made.  I guess it depends on the solution.  Also, what are you refering to for non-selectable?  The above code reports correctly even if the layer is locked or if a shape has it's LockSelect cell set to true.  Is there another property that I've forgotten?

Comment: Hi @John, No, it was the LockSelect bit I was thinking of. For many (most) people, the local name is what they'll be using, but for us lucky enough to use English then the Flowchart layer name is the same via .Name and .NameU but in other languages the .Name will be what they see. As, of course, you know!!!! Just needed to make the point for those not aware of this subtlety.

Comment: Hi @Paul, well you're quite right to call out the difference.  If you're coding against a live document (or accepting user input) then I agree you're more likely to want to manipulate the the names you can see (local) and if you're writing an addin that might be used against multiple documents then universal syntax is the way to go.